# Rewrite URL so the first folder will be removed from URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**Problem**

I try to compose a RewriteRule that rewrites this

```
http://my.domain.pl/subdir/a/b/c/d/foo.bar
```

into this

```
http://my.domain.pl/subdir/b/c/d/foo.bar
```

There is no `a/` folder in target URL.

`subdir` is the folder where .htaccess is placed. The rule must remove the first folder next to `subdir` regardless how many folders are after it in the path.

So for example this

```
http://my.domain.pl/subdir/a/b/c/d/ghi/hij/foo.bar
```

should be rewrited into this

```
http://my.domain.pl/subdir/b/c/d/ghi/hij/foo.bar
```

as well.

**My approach**

I prepared the rule but it did not work as I expected:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.+)\.([^/]+)$ $1.$2 [L]
```

This rule rewrited

```
http://my.domain.pl/subdir/a/b/c/d/foo.bar
```

into

```
http://my.domain.pl/subdir/foo.bar
```

What is strange a very similar rule, that has not got period in `$1.$2`but nothing a letter was rewrited as I expected. I mean such a rule:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.+)\.([^/]+)$ $1x$2 [L]
```

It rewrited this

```
http://my.domain.pl/subdir/a/b/c/d/foo.bar
```

into this

```
http://my.domain.pl/subdir/b/c/d/fooxbar
```

Escaping the period in the rule like this `$1\.$2` did not help.

**Question**

How to create the rule to remove the first folder of the path?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a proper regex pattern to match the requested uri.Try this :

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*?)/(.+\.[^/]+)$ /subdir/$1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: It does not work. This path shrinking is executed several times in loop. The same problem is for my rule. So we must make a rule to process shrinking only ones. We can add a RuleCond to check if the `a` folder exists and do rewriting when it exists only but then the name of the folder should be known.